# Do sequential secret seeds create a security risk?

Tags: security, wallets

In developing a hierarchical deterministic wallet, want to generate one random secret seed and declare it as the **Master Secret Seed**.

Then, add a sequential index (1, 2, 3,... **n**) to the **Master Secret Seed** to obtain a secret seed to generate key pairs for each one.

The maximum index number **n** will be less than a thousand.

Would this approach imply any security risk at all?

All secret seeds (including the **Master Secret Seed**) will be kept secret always. And the **Master Secret Seed** will NOT be used to create a keypair (no index 0 keypair)

My concern is that an attacker could log the public keys knowing that all come from sequential secret seeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's alright as long as your **Master Secret Seed** is truly random.
Remember that thousand of seeds is still a drop in the ocean of all possible keys.

Even though seeds will be sequential - you won't be able to tell that looking at public addresses, and there is no way to restore number of public addresses back into secrets/seeds even if you have full sequence.
The only risk here is that leak of 1 key leads to compromise of all of them.

Why aren't you using standard way of doing HW wallet?
Like that one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stellar-hd-wallet

You have 1 seed and all keypairs derived from it using index (0,1,...,n)